# how to identify or detect scanner from network using java library in spring boot?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, twain, image-scanner, morena

I am using ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit OS . I am trying to scan image from scanner. I am trying  since 5 days. I have used Jsane , twain. i have also try to search Jsane and twain dependency for maven project but i was fail.
I have also try to find morena 7, jar and maven dependency. I am not sure which jar and dependency is use for scanning image from scanner. Please suggest me if there is any better way .  I am tired

Comment: could you provide more detail of what youve tried? i.e how?, your code etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following post and update the question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please help me still i am trying

Comment: @VimalVasava have you found solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried but didn't get so much luck.

I am able to detect printer using javax library

```
PrintService _service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService(); 
if (service != null) 
{ 
    String printServiceName = _service.getName(); 
    System.out.println("Printer Service Name is " + printServiceName); 
} 
else 
{ 
    System.out.println("No printer service found"); 
}
```